# Convert Observable of one type to another

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java2

I have the following code

```
class CurrencyRepository @Inject constructor(val apiInterface: ApiInterface,
                                             val ratesDao: RatesDao) {
    fun getRates(): Observable<List<Rates>> {
        val observableFromApi = getCurrencyFromApi()
        val observableFromDb = getRatesFromDb()
        return Observable.concatArrayEager(observableFromApi , observableFromDb)
    }

    private fun getCurrencyFromApi(): Observable<Currency> {
        return apiInterface.getRates()
                .doOnNext {
                    Timber.i(it.toString())
                    val map = it.rates
                    val keys = map.keys
                    for (key in keys) {
                        ratesDao.insertRate(Rates(key , map.get(key)))
                    }
                }
    }

    private fun getRatesFromDb(): Observable<List<Rates>> {
        return ratesDao.getAllRates()
                .toObservable()
                .doOnNext {
                    for (rate in it) {
                        Timber.i("Repository DB ${it.size}")
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

In `getCurrencyFromApi()`, `getRates()` returns me an `Observable<Currency>`. I would like this particular function to return `Observable<List<Rates>>` so that I can use it in `Observable.concatArrayEager` inside `getRates()` of `CurrencyRepository`

Currency contains a Map object which can be transformed into a List object. I am not clear on how to do that inside `getCurrencyFromApi()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solutions is

```
fun getRatesFromApi(): Observable<List<Rates>> {
    return apiInterface.getRates()
        .flatMapIterable { it.rates.entries }
        .map { Rates(it.key ,it.value) }
        .doOnNext { ratesDao.insertRate(it) }
        .toList()
        .toObservable()
}
```

I advise you insert items in database in one batch, because it will be more efficient.